I want to create API for stable diffusion outpainting
Here is what I tried and it did not worked, I want to create some solution that will enable me to connect to my stable dyffusion model, send a img there and "make that img bigger"/outpaint that and add some bacground. In automatic1111 it is possible I want to do the same, how to do it?
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

    def outpaint_with_model(image_path, model):
        input_image = Image.open(image_path)
        outpainted_image = model.sample_posterior(input_image, num_samples=1)
        return outpainted_image
    
    def start():
        model_path = "./model/realistic-model.safetensors"
        input_image_path = "./generated_images/generated_image_20240517_123639.png"
    
        safety_checker = StableDiffusionSafetyChecker.from_pretrained("CompVis/stable-diffusion-safety-checker")
        feature_extractor = CLIPImageProcessor.from_pretrained("openai/clip-vit-base-patch32")
    
        model = StableDiffusionXLPipeline.from_single_file(model_path,
            safety_checker=safety_checker,
            feature_extractor=feature_extractor)
    
        outpainted_image = outpaint_with_model(input_image_path, model)
    
        outpainted_image.show()
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        start()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PBG\Desktop\holder\StableDiffusionApi\SDMain\main.py", line 87, in <module>
    start()
  File "C:\Users\PBG\Desktop\holder\StableDiffusionApi\SDMain\main.py", line 80, in start
    outpaintedimage = outpaintwithmodel(inputimage_path, model)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PBG\Desktop\holder\StableDiffusionApi\SDMain\main.py", line 60, in outpaint_with_model
    outpainted_image = model.sample_posterior(input_image, num_samples=1)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PBG\Desktop\holder\StableDiffusionApi\SDMain\venv\Lib\site-packages\diffusers\configuration_utils.py", line 142, in __getattr
    raise AttributeError(f"'{type(self).__name}' object has no attribute '{name}'")
AttributeError: 'StableDiffusionXLPipeline' object has no attribute 'sample_posterior'


where did you get StableDiffusionApi ? In question (not in comments) you could add link to documentation. Error shows that it doesn't have sample_posterior. Maybe it has different name

I am new to python so I used gpt for that, it suggested these solution, and also I was not able to find how to outpaint other way. In case of just using model I had to use: from diffusers import StableDiffusionXLPipeline. I tried to do the same in case of outpaint

it seems here is homepage for diffusers with documentation and tutorials and you may have to read it. And there is source code for diffusers and you can check in source code if it has some function or not. It seems StableDiffusionXLPipeline can't be used with outpaint_with_model because it doesn't have function or variable sample_posterior

thx for answer, you are not aware maybe how to create outpainting in some different way?
